# in iOS How to apply lazy loading while fetching images and videos from assets?

Tags: ios

I have fetched the images and videos from gallery, it works fine when the number of videos and images is minimum,but when the number of images and videos is large, it blocks the main thread.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
// call the same method on a background thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [self getAllVideosAndImages];

});
}
```

To gat Images and Videos From Asset

```
-(void)getAllVideosAndImages{
NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAll;

void (^assetEnumerator)
( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != nil) {
        if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]||[[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {
            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [result defaultRepresentation];

            CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
            if (iref) {

                //GET DATE
                NSDate *myDate = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDate];
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd,YYYY"];
                NSString *realDateStr = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
                //GET IMG AND VIDEO
                UIImage *largeimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
                NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(largeimage);
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%zd.mov",imgName]];
                imgName=imgName+1;
                [webData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
                Para_ImageSet *objImgSet=[Para_ImageSet new];
                objImgSet.imagePath=localFilePath;
                objImgSet.imageDate=realDateStr;
               // [yArrayOfAllImges addObject:objImgSet];

                if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]) {
                    objImgSet.is_video=YES;
                }
                else
                {
                     objImgSet.is_video=NO;
                }

                if ([tempDate isEqualToString:@""]) {
                    yArrayOfImagesWithDate=[NSMutableArray new];
                    [yArrayOfImagesWithDate addObject:objImgSet];
                    tempDate=realDateStr;
                }else
                {

                        //GATE IMAGE COUNT
                        if ([realDateStr isEqualToString:tempDate]) {
                            //DO NOTHING
                           [yArrayOfImagesWithDate addObject:objImgSet];

                        }
                        else
                        {



                            [yArrayOFNNestedImgs addObject:yArrayOfImagesWithDate];
                             NSLog(@" ----------ImagesWithDate =%zd, %@",yArrayOfImagesWithDate.count,tempDate);
                            yArrayOfImagesWithDate=[NSMutableArray new];
                            [yArrayOfImagesWithDate addObject:objImgSet];
                            tempDate=realDateStr;







                        }
                }


            }

        }

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
};

void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        [assetGroups addObject:group];
      //  NSNumber *countObj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:count];
        NSLog(@" ----------ImagesWithDate =%zd, %@",yArrayOfImagesWithDate.count,tempDate);
        [yArrayOFNNestedImgs addObject:yArrayOfImagesWithDate];
        NSLog(@" ----------Count =%zd",yArrayOFNNestedImgs.count);

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10];
        // update UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });

    }
};


[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupTypes
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {NSLog(@"A problem occurred");}];
}
```

Please Suggest..Thanks in advance.

Comment: even if it is large it shouldnt block the main thread, isnt that's why u are dispatching it in a separate queue using GCD?

Comment: Bad, do not use `sleepForTimeInterval:`

Comment: Ok, but if the data is large, it takes too much time to display...so I want to perform lazy loading, thats why I used 'sleepForTimeInterval:' , so user should not get stuck until the data is not loaded completely..if you have any other solution please suggest?

Answer (score 2):

`[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];` is blocking main thread for a second. It's not needed.

You could use `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getAllVideosAndImages) withObject:nil];`

Also, wrap first `[self.tableView reloadData];` in
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    ...
});` too

Comment: after some time it get crashed and gives error "Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died"

Comment: 1. Are you sure that you aren't calling any UIView-related methods on non-main queue?

2. Try to put assetGroups and library into the atomic properties of this object

Comment: I have implemented the changes what you told me...but steel I am facing the same problem..And I observe that if I don't scroll the tableview ,it haven't crash, when I am trying to scroll the tableview it gives me memory warning and then "Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died"....

Comment: also when I give static image instead of Asset images ...it works properly...with the same array count that I have retrieved from Assets Library.

Comment: done..I was using Full resolution image instead of  thumbnail..and also the problem was atomic property was not set..Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

In order to lazily load the resources, here is the recommended approach:

1. Download URLs of all resources and store them into your container (array / objects etc)
2. Fire a [NSURLSessionTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/) (post iOS 7 only) which runs async on background queue. If you are below iOS 7, you can use [NSURLConnection SendAsynchronousRequest API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:) - it's deprecated in iOS 9 so you better get rid of that soon.
3. Process your downloaded resources while on background queue - store audio/image files, create UIImage from NSData, and so on.
4. Come back to main queue, then update the relevant UI part with downloaded content. If audio/video, play it. If UIImage, display it.

Here - the entire approach is [described in my tutorial](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ios-app-design-blog-load-images-asynchronously-inside-uitableview/).